# Flutter One Signal 5.0.1 Send Notification

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I was using this Flutter code to Create Notification when using OneSignal 3.5.1

```
var notification = OSCreateNotification(
    playerIds: listOneSignalUserId,
    androidSmallIcon: 'ic_stat_one_signal_default',
    androidLargeIcon: 'ic_stat_one_signal_default',
    content: message,
    androidSound: sound,
    heading: title,
    languageCode: 'en',
    iosAttachments: {
      "id1": imgUrlString
    },
    //url: url,
    //bigPicture: imgUrlString,
    buttons: [
      OSActionButton(text: "OK", id: "id1"),
    ]);

var response = await OneSignal.shared.postNotification(notification);
```

And it works fine

But when upgrading to OneSignal 5.0.1, there are some changes
which OSCreateNotification class is missing

Any suggestion how to Create notification from App ?

Comment: I guess they are changing it to OSNotification class and if so then we need to pass Map<String, dynamic> json

I feel that this new method may more prone to error

But I haven't successfully try with this OSNotification

Any Sugesstion ?

Comment: var notification = OSNotification({
      '': '',
      'smallIcon': 'ic_stat_one_signal_default',
      'largeIcon': 'ic_stat_one_signal_default',
      'title': '$title',
      'sound': '$sound',
      'body': '$message',
      'buttons': '[OSActionButton(text: "OK", id: "id1")]',
    });

Comment: But then How to Post that Notification like                

var response = await OneSignal.shared.postNotification(notification);